# Change layer styles based on ComboBox search?

Tags: wms, geoext, ext-js, boundless-suite, combo-box

I'm using a combination of OpenGeo Server components and hand written GeoExt code to create a map interface. I would like to have a ComboBox that queries the OpenGeo PostGIS database in order to create a list of counties in a state. As the user begins typing the ComboBox searches the store of counties to narrow down to the one they are looking for. Upon selecting the county I would like to change the style of the layer in order to show the selected county.

Using the GeoExplorer I am able to create various styles in a single layer that relate to certain rules. For example:

I have a layer that references 100 counties in a state. The layer is made up of 100 different shape geometries, each of which defines a single county. I have one layer style that outlines the counties like this:

```
<sld:NamedLayer>
<sld:Name>opengeo_CountiesNC_OSM</sld:Name>
<sld:UserStyle>
  <sld:Name>opengeo_CountiesNC_OSM</sld:Name>
  <sld:Title>A transparent stroked polygon style</sld:Title>
  <sld:IsDefault>1</sld:IsDefault>
```

I have another layer style that refers to only a specific county and outlines it. This style uses a rule "Match: Name = Durham" in order to determine which county to outline.

```
<sld:NamedLayer>
<sld:Name>County Lines_5f024dcb</sld:Name>
<sld:UserStyle>
  <sld:Name>County Lines_5f024dcb</sld:Name>
  <sld:Title>Durham</sld:Title>
  <sld:Abstract>County lines for only Durham County</sld:Abstract>
  <sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
    <sld:Name>name</sld:Name>
```

I would like to have a style that represents each of the counties in the layer so that they could be individually selected and shown on the map. Rather than have 100 different layers I believe it is easier to have 100 styles.

Is there some way to change which style of a layer is being displayed via GeoExt or OpenGeo JavaScript code? Having a listener on the ComboBox to read the selected record and display the corresponding layer seems ideal. I'm not sure what access I have to the layer styles that are kept in the GeoServer from the web application side of things. What calls can I make in JS to appropriately retrieve and display data?

**Edit**
When creating a WMS Layer there is an optional param "styles" that allows for an array of String style names:

```
new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("County Lines",
                "geoserver/wms",
                {layers: "opengeo:County Lines",
                    transparent: true,
                    styles:[
                        "opengeo_CountiesNC_OSM",
                        "County Lines_Durham"
                    ]},
                {
                    visibility: true,
                    displayInLayerSwitcher: false,
                    opacity: .7
                }
            )
```

With multiple styles imported it should be possible to switch between them?

**EDIT 2**

Ended up doing something similar to the WMS Store. Because I already have a Google Geocoder I discovered that I could hook into the results of that ComboBox to determine when a county had been search for. Once a search had been performed the results can be trimmed and inserted into a merge request.

```
if(str.match(/(\D\s)+County, NC, USA/))
                    {
                        console.log("Match! It's a county");
                        console.log("County Lines_" + str.substring(0, str.indexOf('C')));
                        mapPanel.map.layers[2].mergeNewParams({styles: "County Lines_" + str.substring(0, str.indexOf('C'))});}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes the styles parameter is the way to switch between named styles, you can use mergeNewParams for this on the layer itself. To get a list of all available styles, you can parse them from the WMS GetCapabilities response. GeoExt should have this info available for you in the WMSCapabilitiesStore.